# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jSerialComm in java.library.path

Tags: java, serial-port, unsatisfiedlinkerror

[If I checked this, my program (simple java coding) gives this exception but else it is running and displaying desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyTyL.png)

**Details**
To communicate with the device I have to make a connection with it through comport using SerialPort. I used RxTx library before but it had bug in it so I switched to JSerialComm.
I followed the instructions on the site and install the app according to it.
my program is running but there is this exception below which is now disturbing my desired output.

*"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jSerialComm in java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.1.12-hotspot\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.PowerShell_7.4.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.1.12-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.8.101-hotspot\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.9.5\bin;C:\Users\Toobaa.khan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Toobaa.khan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;."*

**Library using**
jSerialComm-2.10.4.jar

I tried pasting the .jar file in these two path
1- *C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.1.12-hotspot\bin;*
2- *C:\Users\Toobaa.khan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Toobaa.khan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;*

still the same error

[Also this is what I am getting when running my JavaFx APplication project that contains the same Jserial.jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6dfa.png)

**Additional Info**
Platform: Visual Studio Code.

pom.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>app.creatingpdfs</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectcreatepdfs</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fazecast</groupId>
            <artifactId>jSerialComm</artifactId>
            <version>[2.10.3,2.10.4]</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose.pdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>23.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>1.8</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>app.creatingpdfs.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What directory is your *code* in? All these paths being shown are system paths

Comment: 'C:\Users\Toobaa.khan\VS Code\Java Projects'

All my projects are in Java Projects folders.
and all my jar files too which i am using in my project.

Comment: JAVA 8 update 391 is installed in my system (for both x64 and x86)

_C:\Program Files\Java\jre-1.8_

Comment: Installation notes are where?

Comment: Pardon, i'm getting a hang of it after years so i'm a bit confused. can you explain further what are installation nodes and where can i find them in my system?#

Comment: Installation *notes*. Where are they for the software you're using?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows

are you asking for these?

Comment: No, I'm talking about jSerialComm

Comment: https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/

This is where I install it from while following all the instructions.

Comment: I don't really see any *installation* instructions there. So in their absence, I would extract the correct dll from the jar, put it in C:\Users\Toobaa.khan and then set the correct variable *at the command line* as part of the java run invocation: `-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Toobaa.khan`

Comment: https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm/wiki/Installation
https://github.com/Fazecast/jSerialComm#readme - its here.

Also I did that what you said above. but when I run this command  '-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Toobaa.khan' it says * '-Djava.library.path' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

Comment: *Also I did that what you said above.* You didn't ;) You missed the words *as part of the java run invocation* According to the readme, I would *also* add another: `-DjSerialComm.library.path=C:\Users\Toobaa.khan`

Comment: Sorry for asking this dumb question =((( but can you please explain with example that where and how can I set these variables.  I am so much confused as I am trying to run this on cmd prompt and it is not recognizing.

Also idk if its related or not but these are my java and maven information.

my Java version: 21.0.1, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-21.0.1.12-hotspot
My Maven home: C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.9.5

Comment: Pretend you don't have to add anything yet. What is your current `java` command in cmd.exe?

Comment: its **C:\Users\Toobaa.khan>**

and if run as administrator: **C:\Windows\System32>**

Comment: That's just the prompt. There's no command there at all. You must be running it *in some way* or you wouldn't have any errors to report. I *still* don't know *how* you're running it

Comment: Sorry if I hadn't mentioned. I am using VScode to run my java programs.
Its a javafx project which is using this jserial library.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml *formatted as code* please?

Comment: I posted the file as an answer as it is not allowing me to post as a comment. @g00se

Comment: OK. I'll take a look. Meantime, please delete that *answer* and place it *in your question* instead

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing the plugin config with the following:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                    <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>app.creatingpdfs.App</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                    <options>
                        <option>-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Toobaa.khan</option>
                        <option>-DjSerialComm.library.path=C:\Users\Toobaa.khan</option>
                    </options>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Obviously the correct dll will have to be at the path shown